# Android drawlines

Tags: android, draw

Goodmorning everyone 
I have a button that when i click at it , a line is drawing between two points with this code :

```
    private class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(colorr[thecolore[0]]);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawLine(the coordinate);

    }
}
```

the problem is when i click for exemple two times the two lines i need are drawing, but when i loop two times and i use

```
button.PerformClick();
```

only the last line's drawing ! 
what's the problem here and how can i solve this . thanks

Comment: Which are the 2 lines? Can you also display code for PerformClick() as well as your click handler?

Comment: PerformClick() is a build-in method that performs a click , the issue here that when i click with my fingers in the button two times two lines draw but when i perform click only one line draws

Answer (score 0):

The onDraw routine needs to draw both lines. You draw it every time the view is invalidated so the onDraw routines needs both lines if you want to draw both lines. It has to draw everything in the view all over again.